# Renderscript bytecode not generating on Android 4.0 Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, renderscript, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

Since installing the new version of ADT (14.0) my renderscript stuff does not compile into bytecode automatically.

Is there a new way to do it that I don't know about?

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: yo kidding? Android 4.0 ICS released already and your phone???

Comment: Was released today. I think the ICS device will be available in November.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my bug in [known issues doc](http://tools.android.com/knownissues)

> Renderscript fails to compile application targeting 11-13. This is due
>   to the build system passing older headers to the compiler [Issue
>   21006]. Workaround: Replace
>   /platforms/android-[11|12|13]/renderscript with the version
>   located at /platforms/android-14/renderscript